# problems in tranferring flies from windows host to kali linux guest in virtual machine

Tags: kali-linux, virtual-machine, file-copy

I am trying to transfer files from my Windows host to kali guest in kali linux but the

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf file_name_host file_guest
```

does not work because it says

> unknown file system vboxsf

Also the it does not show the USB in the machine after I added the USB from the device menu in the virtual machine.

So can someone help me know how I can transfer files from Windows host to kali Linux guest

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to accomplish this would be to use
[PSCP](http://putty.org), part of the Putty toolset on your windows machine.

From a Windows command prompt:

```
pscp.exe \path\to\file user@kaliIPaddress:/path/to/destination
```